# send mail via php to microsoft exchange

Tags: php, email

i have function to send mail with attachment to microsoft exchange server. My problem is that when I wanna to add attachment the whole message part is adding my text to attachment source. When I save attachment to body section of mail, my attachment source is wrote down in email body  instead of creating an attachment. Belowe is my source.

```
$eol = "\r\n";

$boundary = md5(time());

    $mail = "explame@explame.com";  

$headers  = "From: no-replay@explame.com".$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; //utworzenie headera wiadomosci
$headers .= "Content-type: multipart/alternative; charset=utf-8".$eol;
$headers .= "Message-ID:< TheSystem@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">".$eol; 
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion().$eol;
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=\"".$boundary."\"".$eol; 
$headers .= "--$boundary".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol;
$headers .= "--$boundary--".$eol.$eol;

if ($file != ''){
    $handle = fopen($file['tmp_name'], 'rb');
    $f_content = fread($handle, $file['size']);
    $attachment =  chunk_split(base64_encode($f_content));
    fclose($handle);

    $content .= "--$boundary".$eol;
    $content .= "Content-type: ".$file['type'].'; '.'name="'.$file['name'].'"'.$eol;
    $content .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file['name'].'"'.$eol.$eol;
    $content .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
    $content .= $attachment.$eol.$eol;
    $content .= "--$boundary--".$eol.$eol;

    }
mail($mail, 'title', $content, $headers)
```

i think I tried everything but nothing works for me. :(

Comment: You should really use a library like SwiftMailer. Sending HTML e-mail is a solved problem.

Comment: Pear mail package will make your life a lot easier.   http://pear.php.net/package/Mail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a really good PHP lib for sending mail (especially for dealing with attachments) is the phpmailer class.

You can find it here: http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

EDIT - the above link is to the old project, it's now hosted on Github and more regularly maintained: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

And an example of how to use it to send an attachment:

```
include("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();    
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->SetFrom('from@mydomain.com');
$mail->AddReplyTo('from@mydomain.com'); //set from & reply-to headers
$mail->AddAddress('to@exchangeserver.com'); //set destination address

$mail->Subject="some subject"; //set subject
$mail->Body="some body HTML <br/><br/>"; //set body content

$mail->AddAttachment('filepath', 'filename'); //attach file

$mail->AltBody = "Can't see this message? Please view in HTML\n\n";
$mail->Send();
```